# Расположение виртуальной среды в проекте

Tags: python, django

хотел узнать, есть ли какие-то правила, или может быть договоренности, в расположении виртуальной среды в проекте?

Comment: `virtualenv` не коммитят, так что нет

Comment: не забудьте название среды в `.gitignore` добавить